*ngIf is not hiding the div in Angular 17
I'm trying to show a div if the conditions for *ngIf are met. I'm just not able to get it done. I have been trying this for hours.
<div *ngIf="item.billingItem=='Staff'">This is NOT showing. I don't know why</div>

However, the same condition is working:
<div>{{item.billingItem=='Staff'?'This is working':''}}</div>

What am I doing wrong? I feel like it's a silly mistake.

*ngIf="item.billingItem == 'Staff'" keeping spaces before and after == should fix the problem.

I think it's because of the missing 'CommonModule'. I'll try another method. Thank you.

have you import the ngIf directive in the component?

Since you are using angular17 go for @if no imports needed
@if (item.billingItem=='Staff') {
    <div>This is NOT showing. I don't know why</div>
}

We also have @if and @else
@if (item.billingItem=='Staff') {
    <div>This is NOT showing. I don't know why</div>
} @else {
    <div>This is showing. I don't know why</div>
}

Angular control flow tutorial

Oh wow! Thank you. Didn't know about this and it works.
Can we use @if (condition) {} else {} like this?

@ElaineByene updated my answer, there are even more features go to angular.dev to check them out
